# PHP / MySQL query. Select either the one or the other

Tags: php, mysql, select

I was trying to select pretty specific data from the database but my query does not seem to work. Is this query correct?

```
SELECT * 
FROM matches 
WHERE compo_id = '1' 
    AND match_id < '5' 
    AND clan_user_id_1 = '0' 
    OR clan_user_id_2 = '0'
```

So I want to select all matches where either clan_user_id_1 or clan_user_id_2 equals zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap it in parenthesis, does this work?

```
 SELECT * FROM matches WHERE compo_id = '1' 
 AND match_id < '5' 
 AND (clan_user_id_1 = '0' OR clan_user_id_2 = '0')
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM
  matches
WHERE
  compo_id = 1
    AND
  match_id < 5
    AND
  (
    clan_user_id_1 = 0
      OR
    clan_user_id_2 = 0
  )
```

Also, unless you really need everything, its usually best not to *SELECT **. Explicitly define which fields you need selected.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
SELECT * FROM matches WHERE compo_id = '1' AND match_id < '5' AND (clan_user_id_1 = '0' OR clan_user_id_2 = '0')
```

Answer (score 1):

When mixing up AND and OR clauses like that, you've got to specify brackets to make it explicitly clear what you want.

You've got

```
A and B and C or D
```

which can get interpreted various ways:

```
A and B and (C or D)
```

or

```
(A and B and C) or D
```